# fullcalendar v5 doesn't render in stepper

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

i have a stepper and want to load Fullcalendar v5 in the second step but the calendar doesn't render correctly if its not in the first step .

[image]

second step
[image]

i'm following the same code from FC examples ( https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals-demo )

Notes: i'm loading the fullcalendar script and style .

also no errors in the console .

index.html (in the second step of stepper)

```
<div id='calendar' style="width: 100%;margin: 40px auto;"></div>
```

stepper.js

```
(function ($) {
  var navListItems = $("div.setup-panel div a"),
    allWells = $(".setup-content"),
    allNextBtn = $(".nextBtn"),
    allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr("href")),
      $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass("disabled")) {
      navListItems.removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-default");
      $item.addClass("btn-success");
      allWells.hide();
      $target.show();
      $target.find("input:eq(0)").focus();
    }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function () {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
    nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]')
    .parent()
    .next()
    .children("a"),
    
    // Validation
    curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
    isValid = true;

    // If it is the second step initialize calendar
    if (isValid && nextStepWizard[0].innerText === '2') {
      initCalendar();
      nextStepWizard.removeClass("disabled").trigger("click");
    }

    if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeClass("disabled").trigger("click");
  });

  allPrevBtn.click(function () {

    
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
    
    prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]')
    .parent()
    .prev()
    .children("a");
    

    prevStepWizard.trigger("click");
  });


  $("div.setup-panel div a.btn-success").trigger("click");
})(jQuery);
```

calendar.js

```
const initCalendar = function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    initialDate: "2021-01-07",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
    },
    events: [
      {
        title: "All Day Event",
        start: "2021-01-01",
      },
      {
        title: "Long Event",
        start: "2021-01-07",
        end: "2021-01-10",
      },
      {
        groupId: "999",
        title: "Repeating Event",
        start: "2021-01-09T16:00:00",
      },
      {
        groupId: "999",
        title: "Repeating Event",
        start: "2021-01-16T16:00:00",
      },
      {
        title: "Conference",
        start: "2021-01-11",
        end: "2021-01-13",
      },
      {
        title: "Meeting",
        start: "2021-01-12T10:30:00",
        end: "2021-01-12T12:30:00",
      },
      {
        title: "Lunch",
        start: "2021-01-12T12:00:00",
      },
      {
        title: "Meeting",
        start: "2021-01-12T14:30:00",
      },
      {
        title: "Birthday Party",
        start: "2021-01-13T07:00:00",
      },
      {
        title: "Click for Google",
        url: "http://google.com/",
        start: "2021-01-28",
      },
    ],
    height: 1200,
  });

  calendar.render();
};
```